# How to choose the resistances for this current generator?

Tags: circuit-design

I have to design a current generator (schematics in figure) which gives as output about \$10\ \text{mA}\$ if it receives as input \$5\ \text V\$. I have to choose the resistances \$(R_1, R_2, R_3, R_4, R_5)\$ which allow me to get this output.

[image]

I think [this](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TCA0372-D.PDF) is the datasheet of the TCA0372.

I do not understand how this circuit works, and how can I choose the resistances

**EDIT:**

I chose  \$R_1=R_2=R_3=R_4=1\$ \$\text k\Omega,\$ in order to get the gain $$G=1\implies V_{out}=V_{in}=5 \ \text V$$ Then \$R_5=465\ \Omega\$ so \$I_{out}=V_{out}/R_5\$ and the load resistance \$R_L=150\  \Omega\$
and I got \$I_{out}=11\$ \$\text{mA}\$

Comment: You have a differential amplifier and a voltage follower. Which part don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand how can the differential amplifier output a current

Comment: What does a resistor do?

Comment: It reduces the current flow

Comment: Incorrect. It relates voltage and current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRjvwp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

hi,

I don't really see a current source.
This should be the behaviour of the circuit:

OA2 is a voltage follower, provides a impedance transformation so that the feedback does not change the output current.

\$V_+\$ should be the +Input of OA1.

The current through R3 and R4 must be the same as no current will flow into the OA1.
$$ \frac{V_\mathrm{in}-V_\mathrm{x}}{R_3} = \frac{-V_\mathrm{out}+V_\mathrm{x}}{R_4} $$

The voltage \$V_+\$ must be the same as \$V_-\$ of the OA1 which is the voltage at the \$ R_1 \$.
$$ V_+ = V_- = V_\mathrm{out} \frac{R1}{R1+R2} $$

Combining both equations and reordering gives

$$ V_\mathrm{out} = \frac{V_\mathrm{in}}{\frac{R_3}{R_4}\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}-\frac{R_3}{R_4}+\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}}\,.$$

So, I would rather say this is a voltage source.

Regards.

Comment: The document from which I got the circuit says this is a current source

Comment: do you have a constant load?

Comment: I have to put a resistor R=100 ohm to close the circuit, is that the load?

Comment: Calculating Vout/(R_equivalent) equals 11 mA, which is about what was I looking for, is that right?

Comment: If you want to have 10mA at the output, with an imput voltage of 5V, and the 100 Ohm as a load, you need to have 1V as Vout, when Vin is 5V. 
The voltage from the ouput will be directly at your load (R=100), as the cuircuit makes a constant voltage at the ouput.

Answer (score 0):

Which resistor  ratios determine voltage gain for this differential amplifier?

What is output current when diff. Input =0 for any load Connected to any voltage within range?

Next For any differential voltage game whether it is one or 1000 and for any load resistance, how does how to put our affect the current with respect to the input voltage gain?  This ties in comments about what R does.

And lastly how does the noninverting input resistor that normally goes to ground or say Vcc/2 , affect the output of the op amp and does connecting to load to a different Voltage other than 0V affect the current out?